# Is ref-copying a compiler optimization, and can I avoid it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I dislike pointers, and generally try to write as much code as I can using refs instead.

I've written a very rudimentary "vertical layout" system for a small Win32 app. Most of the Layout methods look like this:

```
void Control::DoLayout(int availableWidth, int &consumedYAmt)
{
  textYPosition = consumedYAmt;
  consumedYAmt += measureText(font, availableWidth);
}
```

They are looped through like so:

```
int innerYValue = 0;
foreach(control in controls) {
  control->DoLayout(availableWidth, innerYValue);
}
int heightOfControl = innerYValue;
```

It's not drawing its content here, just calculating exactly how much space this control will require (usually it's adding padding too, etc). This has worked great for me.......in *debug* mode.

I found that in Release mode, I could suddenly see tangible, loggable issues where, when I'm looping through controls and calling `DoLayout()`, the `consumedYAmt` variable actually stays at 0 in the outside loop. The most annoying part is that if I put in breakpoints and walk through the code line by line, this stops happening and parts of it are properly updated by the inside "add" methods.

I'm kind of thinking about whether this would be some compiler optimization where they think I'm simply adding the *ref* flag to ints as a way to optimize memory; or if there's any possibility this actually works in a way different from how it seems.

I would give a minimum reproducible example, but I wasn't able to do so with a tiny commandline app. I get the sense that if this is an optimization, it only kicks in for larger code blocks and indirections.

EDIT: Again sorry for generally low information, but I'm now getting hints that this might be some kind of linker issue. I skipped one part of the inheritance model in my pseudocode: The calling class actually calls "`Layout()`", which is a non-virtual function on the root definition of the class. This function performs some implementation-neutral logic, and then calls `DoLayout()` with the same arguments. However, I'm now noticing that if I try adding a breakpoint to `Layout()`, Visual Studio claims that "The breakpoint will not be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line." I *am* able to add breakpoints to certain other lines, but I'm beginning to notice weird stepping logic where it refuses to go inside certain functions, like `Layout`. Already tried completely clearing the build folders and rebuilding. I'm going to have to keep looking, since I have to admit this isn't a lot to go on.

Also, random addition: The "controls" list is a vector containing shared_ptr objects. I hadn't suspected the looping mechanism previously but now I'm looking more closely.

Comment: That `foreach` looks like C#.  C++/CLI has a `for each`, but it's better to use the ISO standard compliant `for( auto& control : controls )` rather than the MS-specific proof-of-concept syntax

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry - It is C++, but I used pseudocode shorthand to put together the example rather than writing out iterator syntax. I can try to adjust my example to an extremely exact replication if you believe things like looping method to be relevant.

Comment: Thought about smart pointers? Saves a lot of hassle than raw pointers

Comment: This should IMHO always work and should never be optimized out - if the code really is as above. In the real code - any chance that there ad multiple threads, which run concurrently? Then this could be a timing issue.

Comment: Not an answer to your question "how to avoid these optimizations in general" but for your specific example: you can avoid it by passing in the int by value (`int DoLayout(int availableWidth, int innerYValue)`) and having the function return the new amount: `innerYValue += control->DoLayout(availableWidth, innerYValue);`

Comment: @EdHeal I don't really think of references as raw pointers...?

Comment: @EdHeal: There's no room for a smart pointer here -- the lifetime of `innerYValue` is already automatic and needs no help.

Comment: @Katana314 - First statement is that you do not like pointers. I suggest that you have to use them sometimes. Smart pointers are better than raw pointers.

Comment: @CompuChip Thanks. I think I thought of doing that at one point. The reason I decided against it was, for future expansion I could definitely imagine having multiple values go both in and out of the method, and wasn't sure if I wanted to create a class just to hold the new information.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, I can qualify that first line: I dislike raw pointers. I'm fine with smart pointers. I just don't see how they would provide any advantage over a reference here (besides, maybe, cheating a buggy compiler)

Comment: @Katana314: There's no rule that allows an optimizer to mess up the code as you have described it.  Most likely, you have undefined behavior nearby (such as reading an uninitialized value) and then the optimizer makes you no guarantees at all.

Comment: I would always create such a class [as you mentioned to CompuChip] for multiple returned values.  I would do it even if I had just one as you do here, because it allows the change to multiple by justing adding a member instead of lots of edits later

Comment: You can try to return the value, but to me it really seems it could be a timing issue - especially when it works when you step through it (do you do the stepping with the release app? - if it is workign then, the code is definitely not optimized out) - it could be for example, that the fonts are loading too slow and are not initialized yet in the release mode, or some similar issue if something is being calculated in another thread.

Comment: The code as written will not produce results as described. This is a very basic code, and I do not believe any compiler can be buggy to the point of messing this. This is also correct code. I'd rather return the consumed amout to the caller and let the call site do the summation, but this is not the case of the problem here.

Comment: If I am to take a wild guess, I'd say, it is a data race somewhere.

Comment: Try to add a delay before the loop, say Sleep(1000) - if it will work then, it is definitely a timing issue.

Comment: @axalis, and than OP might be tempted simply to leave it there and consider the problem solved (ask me if I've seen such code!). My advice to OP - DO NOT.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, definitely. That should just serve to test whether or not it is a timing issue, but afterwards it should be really resolved differently (perhaps using mutex/critical section/condition etc.).

Comment: It is not reproducible in a small app, are you really sure that it's the optimizer and not the remainig code that you've stripped that causes havock ?  Statistically speaking the latter has a much higher probability...

Comment: To reply to a few queries: will try Sleep soon just to check for race conditions - although I don't know of any second thread that affects relevant resources. Secondly, I know optimizers tend to run in Release but not Debug. I know optimizer bugs are unlikely, just that looking over my code am failing to find any other "intermittent-behavior" nail that might explain the exact conditions I'm seeing. Whatever I find, many thanks for all the suggestions and insight.

Comment: Please don't write solutions in the Question box  (same comment applies to the editor who tweaked it recently)

Comment: I suggest closing the question as "can no longer be reproduced"

Answer (score 1):

"the `consumedYAmt` variable actually stays at 0"

The behavior you describe is typical for a specific optimization that's more due to the CPU than the compiler. I suspect you're logging `consumedYAmt` from another thread. The updates to `consumedYAmt` simply don't make it to that other thread.

This is legal for the CPU, because the C++ compiler didn't put in memory fences. And the CPU compiler didn't put in fences because the variable isn't atomic.

In a small program without threads, this simply doesn't show up, nor does it show in debug mode.

Comment: There is no multithreading in the given example - the entire lifecycle of consumedYAmt exists in a single thread.

Comment: @Katana314: And I'm quite confident that the given example (in isolation) does not exhibit the observed behavior.

Comment: @Katana314: Assuming that threads are the cause of the problem is entirely reasonable. The only other possibility (short of the compiler being broken beyond all reason) is that `measureText` contains an uninitialized variable and thus for some contorted reason happens to return always-zero in one build (adding zero to a reference obviously doesn't affect the referenced value a lot).

Answer (score 0):

*Written by OP*

---

Okay, eventually figured this one out. As simple as the issue was, pinning it down became difficult because of Release mode's debugger seemingly acting in inconsistent ways. When I changed tactic to adding Logging statements in lots of places, I found that my Control class had an "mShowing" variable that was uninitialized in its constructor. In debug mode, it apparently retained uninitialized memory which I guess made it "true" - but in release mode, my best analysis is that memory protections made it default to "false", which as it turns out skipped the main body of the DoLayout method most of the time.

Since through the process, responders were low on information to work with (certainly could've been easier if I posted a longer example), I instead simply upvoted each comment that mentioned uninitialized variables.